# Change text to date formate in R

Tags: r, date

I am trying to extract the date from a column of text in formate of "mm/dd/yyyy".

```
> head(X$A1)
[1]            
2456 Levels:   1/1/2007 1/1/2008 1/1/2009 1/1/2012 1/10/2005 1/10/2006 1/10/2007 ... 9/9/2016
```

I then use as.date to extract the year in the date with decimal places. However, it returns with NA...

```
> X$dates <- as.Date(X$A1, "%m/%d/%Y")

> head(X$dates)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

How can I get the date express in the number of year with decimals? Thanks!

Comment: It might be something else. `as.Date(factor("1/1/2007"), "%m/%d/%Y")` outputs `[1] "2007-01-01"`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Now that you mention it, the `head()` shows levels, but empty values after the `[1]`. Something's wrong with the data.

Comment: Note that the output of `head(X$A1)` does not show values, just levels. That is evidence that something is wrong.

Comment: Agree with @RuiBarradas; `as.Date` has method `as.Date.factor` to deal with `factor`s.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(X$A1))`?

Comment: yes sure..

dput(head(SCNAMES$A1))
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c(" ", "1/1/2007", 
"1/1/2008", "1/1/2009", "1/1/2012", "1/10/2005", "1/10/2006", 
"1/10/2007", "1/10/2008", "1/10/2010", "1/10/2015", "1/11/2005", 
"1/11/2006", "1/11/2007", "1/11/2008", "1/11/2010", "1/11/2011", 
"1/11/2012", "1/11/2013", "1/11/2015", "1/12/2005", "1/12/2006", 
"1/12/2007", "1/12/2008", "1/12/2009", "1/12/2010", "1/12/2011", 
"1/12/2012", "1/12/2013", "1/12/2015", "1/13/2005", "1/13/2006", 
"1/13/2007", "1/13/2015", "1/13/2016", "1/14/2005", "1/14/2006"), class = "factor")

Comment: Based on your `dput`, `SCNAMES$A1` clearly got corrupted. You've got a `factor` where the first level corresponds to a whitespace `" "` and whose entries consist of only white space `" "` entries (you can confirm if you look at `as.character(SCNAMES$A1)`). You need to go back a step and investigate what went wrong when you created `SCNAMES$A1`. My solution below shows you how to convert a date into a decimal of a year. Once you have worked out what went wrong with `SCNAMES$A1` below solution will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are asking how to convert a date to a decimal of its year.

We can use `lubridate::decimal_date` for that

```
# Sample data
date <- c("1/1/2007 1/1/2008 1/1/2009 1/1/2012 1/10/2005 1/10/2006 1/10/2007")
date <- unlist(strsplit(date, " "))
date
#[1] "1/1/2007"  "1/1/2008"  "1/1/2009"  "1/1/2012"  "1/10/2005" "1/10/2006"
#[7] "1/10/2007"

# Convert to decimal dates
lubridate::decimal_date(as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
#[1] 2007.000 2008.000 2009.000 2012.000 2005.025 2006.025 2007.025
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
X$dates <- as.Date(as.character(X$A1), "%m/%d/%Y")
```